# Propriedade "backdrop-filter" do css não funciona no Mobile

Tags: css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Boa noite, gente. Eu aqui com mais um erro, iniciante, batendo cabeça sem conseguir achar o que é o problema. Eu adicionei a propriedade "backdrop-filter" após usar rgba background numa div que consta os links de navegação do menu do site. no Chrome Dev Tools do meu note, a propriedade funciona emulando o Mobile, porém ao acessar do dispositivo físico mesmo, somente a cor rgba funciona, o blur da propriedade não aplica (já tentei acessar pelo Chrome e Safari) =/...

Comment: Vc pode tentar usando filter blur, tem um suporte melhor que backdrop

Comment: Entendi! Porém, eu já tentei só que o filter blur acaba embaçando todos os ítens do menu. =/ - Tenho Ícones e textos :(

Answer (score -1):

Segundo a MDN, a propriedade **backdrop-filter ainda é uma tecnologia experimental**, portanto sempre verificar a compatibilidade da mesma pelos navegadores, e verificar se será usado em ambiente de produção.

Sugiro que você veja no link abaixo a exata compatibilidade de navegadores e versões desta propriedade, tanto para PC quanto para mobile.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter#Compatibilidade_de_navegadores

Comment: Obrigado pela indicação! Pelo que li, os meus browsers seriam "meio compatíveis", mas como sou iniciante, tá tendo imperícia de implementar isso e fazer funcionar, vou deixar de lado enquanto! Obrigado ! :)